# Диаконисса или диакониса?

Tags: орфография

Две "с" появились в результате транслитерация греческого слова διακόνισσα, в котором две стигмы (σσ). Одна "с" может быть аргументирована тем, что слово, войдя в систему русского языка, адаптировалось к существующему морфемному типу: сущ м.р. + суффикс ис: директриса, актриса.

- Вопрос в том, какой вариант выбрать? В орфографических словарях, в МАСе дается это слово с одной "с". В Интернете, т.е. на практике, в большинстве своем это слово с двумя "с".
- Как быть?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Как быть?**

Смотреть словари. Если написание закреплено в словарях, то нет особого смысла руководствоваться логикой происхождения такого написания. Во всех (светских) словарях отмечено написание с одной "с" (я просмотрел не все, конечно, но около десяти, в которых приведено это слово).

Единственное, на что ещё можно обратить внимание — на православные традиции написания этого слова, которые следуют ещё с "синоидального перевода греч. τὴν διάκονον" (см. [эту энциклопедию](http://www.pravenc.ru/text/171915.html)). Если вы работаете с православным издательством для соответствующей целевой аудитории, тогда я не вправе что-то советовать.